# Trajectory of a particle moving in a non-abelian gauge potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, gauge-theory, yang-mills

Particle moving in a abelian Maxwell gauge potential can be understood from Lagrangian
$$
L=(1/2) m \dot{\vec{r}}^2- q\phi +q \dot{\vec{r}}\cdot \vec{A}
$$
or Hamiltonian
$$
H=\frac{(\vec{p}-q  \vec{A})^2}{2m} +q\phi .
$$

We can solve the equation of motion eom and find the Lorentz force law. We can find out the trajectory of particle moving in the magnetic field or electric field. For example,

1. the particle may move in a circular motion or a helical motion under magnetic field.
2. the particle may simply accelerate in a straight line under the electric field.

I was asked to separate my question into different questions - so follow [the first one on Lagragian/Hamiltonian and eom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/625951/42982), now I ask a follow up -

### my questions

- What are the representative trajectories of particle moving in the non-abelian magnetic field or non-abelian electric field?

We can assume the particle has $N=2$-component coupled to the $SU(N=2)$ gauge field via the fundamental representation. Or general $N$.

Comment: Your examples are for motion in *uniform* and *constant* fields but you didn’t mention that. Defining what this means in the non-abelian case is nontrivial since the field tensor is not gauge-invariant. One of the references I listed in a comment on your previous question discusses this.

Comment: Yes. that was a subtle point that I did not write explicitly